# webpack - Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, webpack

When i render my grid, i'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. I've moved the script tag to the head, in order to avoid duplication of the grid. I tried using defer, but it brings the duplication back. Any thoughts?

```
function drawMap() {
    // debugger
    map = document.createElement('div');
    let tiles = createTiles(gameData);
    tiles.forEach(tile => { 
        map.appendChild(tile);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(map);
}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at drawMap (index.js:72)
    at main (index.js:133)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:137)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (main.js:10681)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/main.css">
    <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const map = document.createElement('div')`

Comment: nope, still erring

Answer (score 0):

the reason for duplication was domContentLoaded in addition to invoking main, i was hitting the page twice.